# Verbose error reporting for vega-lite

Tags: vega, vega-lite

I have a series of `transforms` that are not "friends" with the Vega-Lite parser.  Is there a means to get better/more detailed error messages than the following:

[image]

Specifically: the message `Ignoring an invalid transform` *does* report which entry were incorrect. That is a good start. I am wondering if any more specifics than that can be obtained - e.g. via a `verbose` setting

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We don't have different error flags but you can try the new editor at https://vega.github.io/editor/, which uses JSON schema to validate specs before they get passed to the Vega-Lite compiler.

Comment: Ok - just checking. These error messages are not so bad actually  - but always good to know.   I started adding `console.log` and putting breakpoints in chrome